# Waiting time for the first event in an Exponential Distribution with different rate parameters

Tags: exponential-distribution, cumulative-distribution-function

I have a random variable $t$ that follows an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda_1$ in the interval $[0,t_1]$ and an exponential distribution with rate $\lambda_2$ in the interval $[t_1,\infty]$. I want to estimate the probability that there is no event in the time interval $[0,t_2]$, where $t_2>t_1$.

Here is how I have approached this problem.

$\begin{equation}
P(t>t_1+t_2)\\
=\{1-\int_{-\infty}^{t_1}f_{\lambda_1}(t)\}
\{1-\int_{t_1}^{t_2}f_{\lambda_2}(t)\}
\end{equation}
$

Is the correct way to approach this problem? Should the second integral be $\{1-\int_{0}^{t_2}f_{\lambda_1}(t)\}$?

In general, what is the procedure to find the waiting time to the 1st event in a case where the inter-arrival process is non-homogenous?

Comment: Suppose $\lambda_1$ happened to equal $\lambda_2$.  You would likely use a simpler expression for the waiting time involving just one integral.  Is your formula equivalent in that case to the simple expression?

Comment: That is a good point. It is not.

Comment: OK.  The simple expression can be written as an integral.  There is a natural way to break it into an integral over two regions separated at the value $t_1$, which re-expresses it as a sum of two integrals.  Consider why that is so and apply that insight to the case $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$.

Comment: So what you are trying to point out is that $P(t>t_1+t_2) = \{1-\int_{-\infty}^{t_1}f_{\lambda_1}(t) - \int_{t_1}^{t_2}f_{\lambda_2}(t)\}$ ?

Comment: Unless $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2$, the density of the "random variable" does not integrate to 1. If $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2$, it would integrate out to 1 if the $\lambda_1$ rate section ended at $t_1$, then there was a gap of 0 density, and the $\lambda_2$  rate section started at $t_3 = (\lambda_1/\lambda_2) t_1$.  Barring that, a time-inhomogeneos Possion Process, yes, a proper random variable, no.

Comment: @Mark is correct--but your approach appears to be on track and the problem with it can be patched up.  You need to think about what it means for the process intensity to change at time $t_1$ and how that affects the survival function.

Comment: @whuber : I do not understand your response to Mark's comment. His comment refers to the fact the way I have framed the problem seems to be incorrect, as it would not be a valid probability density.

Comment: I think Math1000 has given a nice demonstration.  It differs from your approach by recognizing you have to compute the probability by multiplying a marginal by a conditional probability rather than adding those two probabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\{N(t):t\in\mathbb R_+\}$ be a (non-homogeneous) Poisson process with intensity $$\lambda(t) = \lambda_1\mathsf 1_{[0,t_1)}(t) + \lambda_2\mathsf 1_{[t_1,\infty)}(t).$$ Then for $t_2>t_1$, we have 
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(N(t_2)=0) &= \mathbb P(N(t_1)=0,N(t_2)-N(t_1)=0)\\
&= \mathbb P(N(t_1)=0)\mathbb P(N(t_2)-N(t_1)=0)\\
&= e^{-\lambda_1 t_1}e^{-\lambda_2(t_2-t_1)}.
\end{align}